# Using ConfigParser to delete lines in config file with no sections

Tags: python, linux, configparser

I am trying to change a .conf file on a Linux server, but there are no sections in the .conf file. I want to search in a key/value pair for a specific keyword and then delete a couple of lines above that line and some lines below that line.

How do I go about achieving this when there are no section headers? Should I even be using ConfigParser?

Also, there are repeating key names throughout the file. In the code section below, I want to search for 'keyword' in the "directory" line and the delete two lines above and the rest of the stuff below that.

```
database        ldbm
loglevel        0
directory       /home/name/NameServer/var/openldap-ldbm-CMDB-keyword
suffix          "o=CMDB-keyword"
suffix          "dc=CMDB-keyword,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=admin,o=CMDB-keyword"
rootpw          (blahblah)
schemacheck     on
lastmod         off
sizelimit       100000
defaultaccess   read
dbnolocking
dbnosync
cachesize       100000
dbcachesize     100000000
dbcacheNoWsync
index objectclass pres,eq                                                      │
index default pres,eq                                                          │
index termName pres,eq
```

Comment: Are you open to using linux tools such as awk or grep?

Comment: Yes grep is on the server. Should I be using that instead of ConfigParser?

Comment: That depends. Can you add more context to the config file snippet above. When you say "delete the rest of the stuff below", how many lines exactly?

Comment: I would delete 2 lines above the directory line and 16 lines below the directory line. Also, including the directory line itself.

Comment: So could this be turned around to say - keep 2 lines above and 16 lines below directory line (plus directory line) if directory line does not contain keyword?

Comment: Exactly. The entire config file follows this same type of Key/Value pairs. I am really only trying to delete one block(section) using a keyword to search.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42262/discussion-between-1-cr-and-d-rock)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each block starts with the `database` line and ends with the `index termName pres,eq` line, this scripts reads from `input.conf` and writes those blocks to `output.conf` that do not contain the `directory....keyword` line

```
import re
with open('input.conf') as f, open('output.conf', 'w') as o:
    s = f.read()
    for x in re.findall(r'^database.*?index termName pres,eq\n', s, 
     re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE):
            if not re.search(r'^directory.*keyword', x, re.MULTILINE):
                    o.write(x)
```